# ExpandableList is not expanding inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, expandablelistview

Previously I was using LinearLayout for my parent and child views , and I made them expand by using below code sniplet in on click of Expandable list parent view :

```
subtask_explist.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            Log.d("subtask_explist" , " pressed");
            setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });

private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView,
                               int group) {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
        groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                        listView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            }
        }
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    int height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
    if (height < 10)
        height = 200;
    params.height = height;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

Old layout files are :

child_row_ad_subtask.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="@color/white_color"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/cb_subtask" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_subtask"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Single-line item"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:clickable="false">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And now I had updated  my code and change root layout "LinearLayout" to "Relative Layout":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="@color/white_color"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_subtask"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtask"
        android:paddingLeft="56dp"
        android:paddingTop="17dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Single Line Item "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now same method setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition); is not working , giving error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
at com.ujjawal.test.testdesignapplication.MainActivity.setListViewHeight(MainActivity.java:227)
at com.ujjawal.test.testdesignapplication.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:21)
at com.ujjawal.test.testdesignapplication.MainActivity$2.onGroupClick(MainActivity.java:126)
at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:561)
at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:539)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2859)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3533)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have 3 expandable list one below another in same layout , if I remove scrollview everything works fine but without scrollview on expanding list other lists below that goes out of screen .

I want to have all 3 listviews with expanding behaviour.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: All group have children right ? make sure you have proper handling for the getChildCount in the adapter. Btw which is line number 227 in main activity ?

Comment: There is only one group in this expandable list & it is containing children 

@Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return  childItems.size();
    }

Line number 227 in main activity is : 
            groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

in method I provided in description.

Thanx for replying :)

Waiting for exact answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);

//here you may be getting groupItem as null. Before calling anyMethod on groupItem you needs to add a null check

if(groupItem!=null)
{
groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
}
// This is one solution. But we need to identify listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView); why this call is returning null. can you post your getGroupView method of the adapter ?
```

**Update**
put null check on overlall code like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
             if(groupItem!=null)
    {
            groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                    || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                            listView);
if(listItem!=null)
{
                    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

 }               }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Now also it is showing null pointer exception

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
at com.ujjawal.test.testdesignapplication.MainActivity.setListViewHeight (MainActivity.java:230)

Comment: Debug and see which object is null. Put breakpoint on the line where you getting the error and check

Comment: Hey Nitish I can send you my code can you please share me your mail id ?

Comment: Thnx for id check your mail .

Comment: Thank u very much for the solution , there are few bugs on rendering can you check on your device

Comment: Wrapping all layouts to Linear solves my problem Thanks Nitin :)